# Application got crashed while execute below code

Tags: c++, vb.net

I called function from Dll which is following.

**testVC2.dll**

```
char * getcheck();

char * getcheck(){
    strcpy(Detail::AMessage, a.auth_answ.Check);
    return Detail::AMessage;
}
```

**My def file.**

```
LIBRARY
EXPORTS
  getcheck @1
```

**My VB code is**

```
Public Declare Function getcheck Lib "testVC2.dll" () As String

 Console.WriteLine(getcheck() )
```

It gives error and application got crashed but when I am trying to return integer from function it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normal way to return a string from C++ to managed languages is to pass StringBuilder as an output argument.

Something like this:

```
//C++
// place your output message into str
void foo(char* str);

//C#
void foo(StringBuilder str);
```

Comment: Make sure that you compile .NET project with correct Platform target property. I mean if you compiled C++ with x86 and it must be in .NET x86 either. AnyCPU changes its behaviour depending on process (x86 or x64).

Comment: I find it and thanks for your help :-) not it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a BSTR instead:

```
#include <comutil.h>

BSTR getcheck();

BSTR getcheck(){

    _bstr_t bstr1(a.auth_answ.Check);
    BSTR bstr;
    bstr = bstr1.copy();
    return bstr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but in my first demo app my code is working .. i want to know is there any privileges so it cant allow me to read or write ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "first demo app"? Do you mean when you return an integer? And does the code above work for you?

Comment: yes, actually i am new in .NET so, before i go to my original project i created an demo application ,that time my code is work but now i am not able to identify , "why it not working right now". actually i created three project . My first project contain DLL function which is compile by win32, my second project use this DLL and which is comiple by "Any Cpu" platform.and finally i am using my 2nd project dll into 3rd project which is also compile in win32 platform

Comment: So that i am trying to compile my 2nd project using win32 but i am not able to find the option of that . it only shows Any CPU option.

Comment: For finding the Win32 option, you should ask this as a new question as other users will not pick it up if it's only in a comment

Comment: If you find any answer has solved your original question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.